# Carrierwave can't find directory and image path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, carrierwave

I am trying to upload images to a Rails 4 app server on Heroku using carrierwave.

In the uploader I have set

```
storage :file

def store_dir
  "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
end
```

The upload is successful and the carrierwave methods current_path and url give

```
/app/public/uploads/photo/picture/1/picture.jpg
```

But when I try to check in the public directory

```
Dir.glob("public/*")
=> ["public/404.html", "public/500.html", "public/robots.txt", "public/422.html", "public/assets", "public/favicon.ico"]
```

No uploads directory.. And thus I can't call File.open or File.new using the path.

Any idea why the upload works and the uploads directory is not listed? (and path not found)

Comment: Are you storing the files in your heroku server? If so, then it won't work. Heroku will let you upload, but they will delete every changed or new added file every 15 minutes. So you can't store anything in heroku, you will have to use Amazon S3 to store the files.

Comment: Very useful to know thx. Yes storing it on heroku server. But actually I wouldn't need the file for more than 15 minutes, since I only need it for an immediate external API call once it's uploaded. Think I should be able to have a working path in that case?

Comment: Nope, even during the 15 minutes, the path does not exist due the ephemeral file system you talk about. Any idea in which directory I can find that file?

Comment: @Coderhs, AFAIK, uploaded files are kept until next push, so this could mean forever if you don't modify your app. At least my uploaded images were stored for a several days until I set up fog-aws